# What is the value of (Vandermonde matrix)$^4~$?

Tags: matrices, primitive-roots

This is Vandermonde matrix:

[image: Vandermonde matrix]

$\omega$ is primitive N-root.

What is $W^4$?
I'm trying to calculate it but I don't know how exactly....

Thank you!

Comment: try to calculate $W^2$ and use the result, $\sum_{i=0}^{i=N-1}\omega^i=0$

Comment: it is not Vandermonde?

Comment: @Kumar - I tried but I don't know exactly how...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly when u say $\omega$ is a primitive N-root, it means it is a root of $X^{N-1}+X^{N-2}+...X+1$ and so is $\omega^{2},...,\omega^{N-1}$.
First try to see what $W^2$ is, what will be the $i+1,j+1^{th}$ element of $W^2$
$\frac{1}{N}(1+\omega^{i+j}+\omega^{2(i+j)}+...+\omega^{(N-1)(i+j)})=0,$ if $i+j\neq0, N, 2N$ and $=1$ if $i=j=0$ or $i+j=N$ or $2N$. So,  
$$W^2=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&0& \dots &0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 &0 & \dots&0&1&0\\
\vdots& \vdots& ⋰&\vdots\\
1&0&\dots&0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore,

$$W^4=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & \dots&0 &2 \\
0 & 1 & \dots&0 &0\\
\vdots& \vdots& \ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&1&0\\
2 & 0 & \dots&0 &2
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It's: $\frac{1}{N}\cdot (1+\omega^{i+j}+\omega^{2(i+j)}+...+\omega^{(N-1)(i+j)})=0,$?

Comment: Yes It is $\frac{1}{N}$, hope it is more clear now. Hope this answered your question

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{N}(1+\omega^{i+j}+\omega^{2(i+j)}+...+\omega^{(N-1)(i+j)})=0$ if $i+j\neq0, N, 2N$?

Comment: because then $\omega^{i+j}$ is a solution of the polynomial above.

Comment: BTW, Why do you put out the $\frac{1}{N}$, where it came from? and how the matrices will be without it? Thank you!!